# Disable clamping in glCopyTexSubImage2D

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, opengl-3

I am attempting to do the following using OpenGL:

1. Render an image to the floating point color attachment of an off-screen framebuffer
2. Allocate an empty texture object with the same format and dimensions as the color attachment
3. Copy the pixels in the color attachment to the texture, as fast as possible

I am using the OpenGL function `glCopyTexSubImage2D` to do the copying. However I found that the copied values are clamped between 0 and 1 in the destination texture.

Right now I am using OpenGL 3.3, but I have to port it to OpenGL ES 2.0 later, so I cannot make use of pixel buffer objects.

I am using the following initialization code, before any copying is done:

```
glClampColor(GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR, GL_FALSE);
glClampColor(GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR, GL_FALSE);
glClampColor(GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR, GL_FALSE);
```

This disables clamping for `glReadPixels` but seems to have no effect on `glCopyTexSubImage2D`.

Is there a way to disable this clamping in `glCopyTexSubImage2D`?

### Edit:

This is for an image processing application with some iterative parts, not for 3D graphics.

Comment: Why not attach the texture as color attachment of the FBO and render directly to it?

Comment: I am doing that in most of my application, but there is a specific iterative part in my application where I need to render something and sample from the result in the next iteration, while keeping the result in the framebuffer. Since the behavior of using the same texture as for reading and writing is undefined, I need to copy.

Comment: It looks like `glCopyTexSubImage2D` always clamps the values. I think you'll have to attach the destination texture to your FBO and render a quad using the (now unattached) texture which has the rendering results so far.

Comment: You may also want to consider using `glBlitFramebuffer()`.

Comment: @EmielBon: That is not completely undefined; NV hardware from that era provides texture barriers to do what you are describing. GL4 era hardware offers image load/store and memory barriers. In any case, I don't see why you can't ping-pong between two different draw buffers for your iterations (in becomes out, and out becomes in on each pass)?

Comment: @RetoKoradi: I want to target OpenGL ES 2.0 in the near future, for which glBlitFramebuffer is not available.

Comment: @AndonMColeman: Thank you, but I am not targeting NV hardware specifically and as you can read in my post, I am not using GL4 (if only I were though...). I don't know how to make clear why I cannot ping-pong between draw buffers, but I just can't. Final attempt: the first iteration draws a full screen image, the next has a shader that discards some pixels that satisfy a predicate, so it leaves some pixels unchanged in the frame buffer. I really just want to know how to disable the clamping, or get some grounded confirmation that it cannot be done.